# How do I make a list loader to reload from a detail Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment, which data is loaded by a SimpleCursorLoader(own imlementation; it loads with a curser and does not use URI).

When an item in the list is selected. I either start up a new activity (detail activity) or I show what is selected in the detail fragment next to the ListFragment. Depending on the screen size.

If the detail fragment is added to the ListActivity, I have figured out how to reload the list. I assign an interface to the ListActivity and call it from the detail fragment, when the change is happening. And in the list fragment I reload the list using getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);

Now my problem is, if the detail activity is loaded, I don't have access to methods on the ListActivity. I could probably implement some observer pattern. But there must be a best practice for this.
How do you make a ListFragment reload the list, when a detail fragment has changed the data in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your list creation code to onResume.  That way it runs on activity creation and every time you go away from the activity and come back.

Comment: But that would make my app refresh the list even when it isn't necessary.

Comment: If you leave the activity, it could very well be necessary.  There's no guarantee that your data will be kept once you leave the activity, this way you don't have to worry about it.